# Angular6: Mat-tree-node selection/click event implementation

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using Angular Material Tree Control with dynamic data.

Here is the link of complete example:

[example is here](https://material.angular.io/components/tree/examples)

It works as mentioned in example. Now i want to enable each node click event and send the (angular expression) bound data in my typescript function.

Can anyone guide me ?

I tried different codes but tree node couldn't be enabled for clicking.

See html :

```
    <mat-tree [dataSource]="dataSource" [treeControl]="treeControl">
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button disabled ></button>
    {{node.item}}
  </mat-tree-node>
  <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasChild" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-icon-button  (click)="applyFilter($event)"
            [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.filename" matTreeNodeToggle>
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
        {{treeControl.isExpanded(node) ? 'expand_more' : 'chevron_right'}}
      </mat-icon>
    </button>
    {{node.item}}
    <mat-progress-bar *ngIf="node.isLoading"
                      mode="indeterminate"
                      class="example-tree-progress-bar"></mat-progress-bar>
  </mat-tree-node>
</mat-tree>
```

I tried this source but still unable to fix it. I tried with stack overflow solutions but it couldn't solve my issue yet.

```
 ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.treeNodes.forEach((reference) => {
      if (!this.hasListener.includes(reference.nativeElement)) {
        console.log('* tick');

        this.renderer.listen(reference.nativeElement, 'click', () => {
          this.updateHighlight(reference);
        });
        this.renderer.listen(reference.nativeElement.children.item(0), 'click', () => {
          this.updateHighlight(reference);
        });

        this.hasListener = this.hasListener.concat([reference.nativeElement]);
      }
    });

    this.hasListener = this.hasListener.filter((element) => document.contains(element));
    console.log('*', this.hasListener.length);
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could wrap your `{{node.item}}` in a mat-button and bind to the click event from there to pass the node element to your component method.

```
<mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodePadding>
    <button mat-button (click)="logNode(node)">
      {{node.item}}
    </button>
</mat-tree-node>
```

Then in your component

```
 logNode(node){
    console.log(node)
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. it is working when i removed first tree node.